# Is it possible to plug x into a problem instead of simply using trial and error?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am currently self teaching IGCSE additional mathematics and I had a question; where better to ask it ;)

When dealing with problem where you already know the total value is there a way to plug in x instead of using tile trial and error?

An example problem is $3X^3-5X^2+6X = 61$; solve for X

Answer (score 0):

To solve the cubic equation you can use [Carano's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method)